# Contribute D8 version of an existing D7 contrib project?

Tags: 8, community-official-site

Can someone describe on how to contribute the D8 version of an existing D7 contrib project? I maintain the D7 project, and further want to add the D8 version of it.

I am struggling with creating 8.x.1.x Dev branch.

Please share any references or steps to follow.

My Project link: [Check DNS](https://www.drupal.org/project/check_dns).

So when I create `8.x.1.x` branch, I can see Drupal 7 specific files within that, so I am confused that how should I manage set of files for D8 and D7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *[Browse code repository](https://www.drupal.org/project/check_dns)* to see your source code on your [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/check_dns). Currently when you go to [list of branches](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/check_dns), the `8.x-1.x` doesn't exist yet.

To maintain both D7 and D8, you need to have one branch for each, `7.x-1.x` for Drupal 7, and `8.x-1.x` for Drupal 8.

To create Drupal 8 out of Drupal 7 version, you should first clone your repository as per [these Git instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2926188/git-instructions/7.x-1.x/maintainer):

```
git clone --branch 7.x-1.x your_user@git.drupal.org:project/check_dns.git
```

then create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b 8.x-1.x
```

which allows you to freely modify your files for Drupal 8 version.

Once you did your conversion, you can push your branch back to Drupal.org, e.g.

```
git push origin 8.x-1.x
```

To switch between branches, use `git checkout` command, so you can contribute to both version.

Ideally, you should read more about managing source code using Git. Checkout this [GitHub Cheat Sheet](https://services.github.com/on-demand/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf).

Comment: Done, thanks. I can't believe that how foolish I was and just overlooked it.
I was using 'ls' command for listing the files in branches :P